# get all elements with througth relation rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through

I have following models :

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :topic_tags
  has_many :tags, through: :topic_tags
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  STATUS_DISABLED = 0
  STATUS_ENABLED  = 1

  has_many :topic_tags
  has_many :topics, through: :topic_tags
end
```

I whant know how get all topics for all tags where status is STATUS_ENABLED.

I would like something like :

```
Topic.where(tags: {status: Tag::STATUS_ENABLED)
```

How the best way to do that?

EDIT:

I found fastidious solution:

```
Tag.includes(:topics).where(status: Tag::STATUS_ENABLED).map(&:topics).flatten
```

better way?

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
Topic.joins(:tags).where(tags: {status: Tag::STATUS_ENABLED}).group("topics.id")
```

That applies an inner join. And it's much better than your `tags.map(&:topics).flatten` solution. The map + flatten queries the database once per enabled tag. This way it's only 1 query.